# Unable to access Custom Metadata Type within LWC using @wire

Tags: lightning-web-components, lwc-wire-adapter

I have a simple Apex and LWC @wire to access Custom Metadata Type (CMT) record:

Apex:

```
    @AuraEnabled
    public static MyCustomMetadataType__mdt getMyCMTRecord(){
        try{
            MyCustomMetadataType__mdt myRecord = MyCustomMetadataType__mdt.getInstance('My_Record');
            return myRecord 
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            System.debug(LoggingLevel.ERROR, 'Exception with message: ' +e.getMessage() );
            throw new AuraHandledException(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

LWC.js:

```
import { LightningElement, api, track, wire } from 'lwc';
import getMyCMTRecord from '@salesforce/apex/My_Handler.getMyCMTRecord'; 

cmtRecord;

@wire(getMyCMTRecord)
wiredCMTRecord({ error, data }){
    if(data){
        this.cmtRecord = data;
        error = undefined;
        console.log('Data: ' +this.cmtRecord ); //It's not getting printed. 
    } else if(error){
        this.cmtRecord = undefined;
        console.log('Error: ' +error);
    }
}
```

I am unable to get the data assigned to my JS property: `cmtRecord`. I don't see any error logs either.

Answer (score 2):

When i am running your code  i am getting error

> "**Error: {"status":500,"body":{"message":"Apex methods that are to be
> cached must be marked as
> @AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)"},"headers":{}}**"

Apex methods  for wire call must be `cacheable = true`.
please update your apex method to have `@AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)`

Edit:
also use `JSON.stringify()`  to see actual data/result , otherwise it will come as `[object,object]`

```
console.log('Data: ' +JSON.stringify(this.cmtRecord) );
```